# Escaping variable in grep statement in conditional statement

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script with this line:

```
if [ -z "`/sbin/service mysqld status | grep 'mysqld (.*) is running'`" ] ; then
```

I want to replace the service name and the grep regex with a variable. Different versions of OS/MySQL have different service names and report different statuses. I'm tired of editing the line in the code. So I did this:

```
SERVICE_NAME=mysql
SERVICE_RUNNING_STR="MySQL (.*) running"
...
if [ -z "`/sbin/service $SERVICE_NAME status | grep '$SERVICE_RUNNING_STR'`" ] ; then
...
```

Except it doesn't work. It outputs SERVICE_RUNNING_STR in the grep statement. I've tried many combinations of quotes and other things and haven't got it to work. I'm not sure what it takes being embedded in quotes and ticks and single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use single quotes, they do not expand variables. Backslash the doublequotes:

```
[ -z "`/sbin/service $SERVICE_NAME status | grep \"$SERVICE_RUNNING_STR\"`" ]
```

Comment: Arg...I knew it was easy. Thought I tried that and it didn't work. Anyway, awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `[ -z ... ]` to see if grep outputs anything, just check grep's exit status (and use its `-q` option to suppress output, and as @choroba pointed out double-quotes around the variable reference):

```
if ! /sbin/service $SERVICE_NAME status | grep -q "$SERVICE_RUNNING_STR"; then
```

Comment: +1 This is what you should use. Much less error-prone than trying to get the quotes right, and avoids the overhead of dealing with output from `grep`.